# Squeeze more speed from Common Lisp / SBCL

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

[This paper](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/~didier/research/verna.06.imecs.pdf) claims to make a certain Lisp program run faster than its C
equivalent. Trying to reproduce the results, I was able to get close (Lisp is
50% slower than C) but wanted to know if anyone knows ways to squeeze more
perf out of SBCL 1.3.1.

The target problem is adding a constant single float to every cell in an 800 x
800 array of single floats. The method is to write the program in C and in
Common Lisp and compare the times. Using this [portable timer](https://github.com/nclack/tictoc), The C code is as
follows:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "./modules/tictoc/tictoc.h"

const int HORZ = 800;
const int VERT = 800;

#define PERF_REPS 1000

typedef float DATA_T;

struct image_s {
    size_t n;
    size_t w, h;
    DATA_T * data;
};
typedef struct image_s image;

image * make_image (size_t w, size_t h) {
    size_t n = w * h;
    DATA_T * data = (DATA_T *)malloc(sizeof(DATA_T) * n);
    assert (NULL != data);
    image * result = (image *)malloc(sizeof(image));
    assert (NULL != result);
    result->n = n;
    result->w = w;
    result->h = h;
    result->data = data;
    return result;
}

void free_image (image * it) {
    assert (NULL != it);
    assert (NULL != it->data);
    free (it->data);
    free (it);
}

image * init_to_value (image * it, DATA_T val) {
    assert (NULL != it);
    assert (NULL != it->data);
    size_t i;
    const size_t n = it->n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        it->data[i] = val;
    }
    return it;
}

void add (image * to, image * from, DATA_T val) {
    assert (NULL != to);
    assert (NULL != to->data);
    assert (NULL != from);
    assert (NULL != from->data);
    size_t i;
    const size_t n = to->n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        to->data[i] = from->data[i] + val;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    image * from = init_to_value (make_image (HORZ, VERT), 0.0f);
    image * to = init_to_value (make_image (HORZ, VERT), 0.0f);
    TicTocTimer clock = tic();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < PERF_REPS; ++i)
        add (to, from, 42.0);
    printf("Elapsed time %f seconds.\n",toc(&clock));
    free_image (to);
    free_image (from);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run the code as follows:

```
gcc -O3 image-add.c ./modules/tictoc/libtictoc.a && ./a.out
```

A typical time on my mac book pro is about 0.178 seconds.  Pretty nice.

The equivalent Lisp code, using every option I was able to find in the Lisp
[hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/common-lisp.html), in the new book [Common Lisp Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484211774), and in the [SBCL user manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/), is
as follows.  The comments indicate some things I tried that did not make a
difference.

```
;;; None of the commented-out declarations made any difference in speed. 

(declaim (optimize speed (safety 0)))

(defun image-add (to from val)
  (declare (type (simple-array single-float (*))
                 to from))
  (declare (type single-float val))
  (let ((size (array-dimension to 0)))
    ;(declare (type fixnum size))
    (dotimes (i size)
      ;(declare (type fixnum i))
      (setf (aref to i) (+ (aref from i) val)))))

(defparameter HORZ 800)
(defparameter VERT 800)

(defparameter PERF-REPS 1000)

(let ((to (make-array (* HORZ VERT) :element-type 'single-float))
      (fm (make-array (* HORZ VERT) :element-type 'single-float)))
  ;(declare (type fixnum HORZ))
  ;(declare (type fixnum VERT))
  (time (dotimes (_ PERF-REPS)
          ;(declare (type fixnum PERF-REPS))
          ;(declare (type fixnum _))
          ;(declare (inline image-add))
          (image-add to fm 42.0))))
```

I compile and run it as follows:

```
sbcl --script image-perf.lisp
```

and typical run times are 0.276. Not bad, but I want it much better. Of course,
the whole point of the exercise is that the Lisp code is shorter, but does
anyone know a way to make it as fast or faster?

Comment: You should use the *file compiler* to actually enable more optimizations. `compile-file`. Loading source code compiles forms individually. The file compiler may do more.

Comment: If I add a `(declaim (inline image-add))` before the definition of the function (and recompile all call sites), I see a speedup (from 0.560s to 0.364s). Could you test that?

Comment: Note also that I see no major difference in timings between the dotimes loop and `(map-into to (lambda (x) (+ x 42f0)) fm)`, which is much shorter. The obvious way to optimize this micro-benchmark code is to forget about the *from* array, which is constantly filled with zeros ;-) Note also that you could parallelize easily the code without major modifications. Replacing `map-into` with `pmap-into` with 4 workers on my machine gives 0.176s of real-time.

Comment: @coredump I added `(proclaim '(inline image-add))` (I couldn't get a `declaim` to work), along with @Rainer Joswig's suggestion to `compile-file` and then load the .fasl file. Neither of these techniques produced appreciable speedup. I run about .300 seconds, give or take with or without these treatments, versus C's ~0.175. I will try multithreading next.  Is it possible that gcc -O3 automatically detects available parallelism from the presence of constants and generates parallel code.  I will figure out how to disassemble it and take a look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For reference, here are some results with a slightly modified version.

#### C version

The C version takes on average **0.197s**.

#### Lisp version

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (debug 0) (safety 0)))

(defconstant HORZ 800)
(defconstant VERT 800)
(defconstant PERF-REPS 1000)

(defun test ()
  (let ((target #1=(make-array (* HORZ VERT)
                               :element-type 'single-float
                               :initial-element 0f0))
        (source #1#))
    (declare (type (simple-array single-float (*)) target source))
    (time 
      (dotimes (_ PERF-REPS)
        (map-into target
                  (lambda (x)
                    (declare (single-float x))
                    (the single-float (+ x 42f0)))
                  source)))))
```

Here is the output:

```
Evaluation took:                                                                                                 
  0.372 seconds of real time                                                                                     
  0.372024 seconds of total run time (0.368023 user, 0.004001 system)                                            
  100.00% CPU                                                                                                    
  965,075,988 processor cycles                                                                                   
  0 bytes consed
```

Replacing `map-into` with `lparallel:pmap-into`, the shortest time is obtained with a kernel composed of 4 workers and gives:

```
Evaluation took:                                                                                                 
 0.122 seconds of real time                                                                                     
 0.496031 seconds of total run time (0.492030 user, 0.004001 system)                                            
 406.56% CPU                                                                                                    
 316,445,789 processor cycles                                                                                   
 753,280 bytes consed
```

Note the difference in memory usage.

Answer (score 10):

### SBCL provides a bunch of information

When I saved your code (and wrapped the final **let** example into a separate function), and compiled it with SBCL, I actually get a bunch of diagnostic output that informs us of some of the places where better code could be generated.  There's a lot of it, but skim through here, though it's all in **test**, so it may or may not be helpful.  But, since the test code might slow things down, it's worth a shot.

```
CL-USER> (compile-file ".../compile.lisp")
; compiling file ".../compile.lisp" (written 25 JAN 2016 01:53:23 PM):
; compiling (DECLAIM (OPTIMIZE SPEED ...))
; compiling (DEFUN IMAGE-ADD ...)
; compiling (DEFPARAMETER HORZ ...)
; compiling (DEFPARAMETER VERT ...)
; compiling (DEFPARAMETER PERF-REPS ...)
; compiling (DEFUN TEST ...)

; file: /home/taylorj/tmp/compile.lisp
; in: DEFUN TEST
;     (* HORZ VERT)
; 
; note: unable to
;   convert x*2^k to shift
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The first argument is a NUMBER, not a INTEGER.
;   The second argument is a NUMBER, not a INTEGER.
; 
; note: unable to
;   convert x*2^k to shift
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The first argument is a NUMBER, not a INTEGER.
;   The second argument is a NUMBER, not a INTEGER.

;     (DOTIMES (_ PERF-REPS) (IMAGE-ADD TO FM 42.0))
; --> DO BLOCK LET TAGBODY UNLESS IF >= IF 
; ==>
;   (< SB-C::X SB-C::Y)
; 
; note: forced to do GENERIC-< (cost 10)
;       unable to do inline fixnum comparison (cost 4) because:
;       The first argument is a UNSIGNED-BYTE, not a FIXNUM.
;       The second argument is a INTEGER, not a FIXNUM.

; --> DO BLOCK LET TAGBODY PSETQ PSETF LET* MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND LET 1+ 
; ==>
;   (+ _ 1)
; 
; note: forced to do GENERIC-+ (cost 10)
;       unable to do inline fixnum arithmetic (cost 1) because:
;       The first argument is a UNSIGNED-BYTE, not a FIXNUM.
;       The result is a (VALUES (INTEGER 1) &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES FIXNUM
;                                                                     &REST T).
;       unable to do inline fixnum arithmetic (cost 2) because:
;       The first argument is a UNSIGNED-BYTE, not a FIXNUM.
;       The result is a (VALUES (INTEGER 1) &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES FIXNUM
;                                                                     &REST T).
;       etc.

;     (* HORZ VERT)
; 
; note: forced to do GENERIC-* (cost 30)
;       unable to do inline fixnum arithmetic (cost 4) because:
;       The first argument is a NUMBER, not a FIXNUM.
;       The second argument is a NUMBER, not a FIXNUM.
;       unable to do inline (signed-byte 64) arithmetic (cost 5) because:
;       The first argument is a NUMBER, not a (SIGNED-BYTE 64).
;       The second argument is a NUMBER, not a (SIGNED-BYTE 64).
;       etc.
; 
; note: forced to do GENERIC-* (cost 30)
;       unable to do inline fixnum arithmetic (cost 4) because:
;       The first argument is a NUMBER, not a FIXNUM.
;       The second argument is a NUMBER, not a FIXNUM.
;       unable to do inline (signed-byte 64) arithmetic (cost 5) because:
;       The first argument is a NUMBER, not a (SIGNED-BYTE 64).
;       The second argument is a NUMBER, not a (SIGNED-BYTE 64).
;       etc.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 6 notes

; .../compile.fasl written
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.009
```

That stuff was all in **test**, but since you *are* timing your **dotimes** loop, it might make sense to at least fix up that comparison.   Here's the **test** code with declarations that should make the **dotimes** a bit quicker:

```
(defun test ()
  (declare (type fixnum HORZ VERT PERF-REPS))
  (let ((to (make-array (* HORZ VERT) :element-type 'single-float))
        (fm (make-array (* HORZ VERT) :element-type 'single-float)))
    (time (dotimes (_ PERF-REPS)
            (image-add to fm 42.0)))))
```

After that you might want to look into possible loop unrolling, caching the array dimension, and considering the memory locality of the arrays.  Those are all pretty generic hints, though.  I'm not sure what specific things could help more here.

### Standard answer about "be sure to use optimize and safety"

> *Edit: shoot, I missed the toplevel declaim that **does** reference speed and safety.  It's still worth checking into whether those are having the desired effect, but if they are, then this answer is mostly redundant.*

For the most part, the compiler is allowed to completely ignore declarations.  (The only exception is **special** declarations, which change the binding semantics for a variable.)  So what a compiler does with them is up to it.  A declaration like **type** could be used in at least two different ways.  If you're trying to compile very **safe** code, type declarations let the compiler know that *additional* checks could be added.  That would result in slower code, of course, but it would be safer.  On the other hand, if you're trying to generate very **fast** code, then the compiler could take those type declarations as your guarantee that the values will always be of the right type, and thus generate faster code.

It looks like you're only adding type declarations.  If you want faster (or safer) code, you'll want to add declarations to say that too.  In this, case, you'll probably want **(declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))**.  For instance, take a look a few disassmblies of just a simple function that returns its fixnum argument. First, just declaring the type, the code ends up being 18 bytes:

```
(defun int-identity (x)
  (declare (type fixnum x))
  x)

INT-IDENTITY
CL-USER> (disassemble 'int-identity)
; disassembly for INT-IDENTITY
; Size: 18 bytes. Origin: #x100470619A
; 9A:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP                     ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 9D:       F8               CLC
; 9E:       5D               POP RBP
; 9F:       C3               RET
; A0:       CC0A             BREAK 10                         ; error trap
; A2:       02               BYTE #X02
; A3:       19               BYTE #X19                        ; INVALID-ARG-COUNT-ERROR
; A4:       9A               BYTE #X9A                        ; RCX
; A5:       CC0A             BREAK 10                         ; error trap
; A7:       04               BYTE #X04
; A8:       08               BYTE #X08                        ; OBJECT-NOT-FIXNUM-ERROR
; A9:       FE1B01           BYTE #XFE, #X1B, #X01            ; RDX
NIL
```

Now, if we also add a speed optimization, the code size goes *up* a little bit.  (That's not necessarily a bad thing, though.  Some speed optimizations, such as loop unrolling or function inlining, will generate bigger code.)

```
CL-USER> 
(defun int-identity (x)
  (declare (type fixnum x)
           (optimize (speed 3)))
  x)

STYLE-WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::INT-IDENTITY in DEFUN
INT-IDENTITY
CL-USER> (disassemble 'int-identity)
; disassembly for INT-IDENTITY
; Size: 20 bytes. Origin: #x1004A5D23D
; 3D:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP                     ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 40:       F8               CLC
; 41:       5D               POP RBP
; 42:       C3               RET
; 43:       CC0A             BREAK 10                         ; error trap
; 45:       04               BYTE #X04
; 46:       19               BYTE #X19                        ; INVALID-ARG-COUNT-ERROR
; 47:       FE9A01           BYTE #XFE, #X9A, #X01            ; RBX
; 4A:       CC0A             BREAK 10                         ; error trap
; 4C:       04               BYTE #X04
; 4D:       08               BYTE #X08                        ; OBJECT-NOT-FIXNUM-ERROR
; 4E:       FE1B01           BYTE #XFE, #X1B, #X01            ; RDX
NIL
```

Finally, when we remove safety, we finally get some *really* short code, just 9 bytes:

```
CL-USER> 
(defun int-identity (x)
  (declare (type fixnum x)
           (optimize (speed 3)
                     (safety 0)))
  x)

STYLE-WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::INT-IDENTITY in DEFUN
INT-IDENTITY
CL-USER> (disassemble 'int-identity)
; disassembly for INT-IDENTITY
; Size: 9 bytes. Origin: #x1004AFF3E2
; 2:       488BD1           MOV RDX, RCX                      ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 5:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; 8:       F8               CLC
; 9:       5D               POP RBP
; A:       C3               RET
```

Comment: Even with the note I put above, I notice that while compiling the file, SBCL gives a number of useful hints, which I'll describe now...

Comment: I repro'd the compiler notes with your `defun test` and verified that it compiles with no notes after adding the internal `declare fixnum`.  Still running about 0.275 seconds on the average :)

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Yeah, doesn't seem to make much of a difference, unfortunately.  A few other things I've been looking to and you might want to consider: function inlining, and passing the array size.  I'm not sure how SBCL stores array sizes, but fetching that every time could have an impact.  Also, check your floating point types.  Do you really want single-float as opposed to double-float (or long-float, etc.)?  But at this point, I think you'll probably want to take a look at how your C disassembles and compare it to what SBCL is generating.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite an old post but you might still be interested.

I would do this if I am after speed!

When we compare speed of C and Common Lisp we need to consider what the C compiler can do with high optimization setting.

Since C with -O3 does do and SBCL doesn't do auto vectorization we have to be careful when we do the comparison.

With vectorization as we can seen bellow SBCL should be plenty fast.

Please install [sb-simd](https://github.com/marcoheisig/sb-simd) first to ~/quicklisp/local-projects.

Then run (ql:quickload :sb-simd) ones to build it.

You need sbcl-2.1.11 to run the latest sb-simd.

The generated vectorized SBCL executable image is faster than the C that is also doing vectorization and most likely loop unrolling as well with the -O3 compiler flag.

EDIT: I've just checked the generated assembly and it is vectorized. With the --march=native --mavx2 the speed did improve slightly.

```
(declaim (optimize speed (safety 0)))
(ql:quickload :sb-simd :silent t)
(use-package :sb-simd)

(declaim (ftype (function (f32vec f32vec f32) null) image-add))
(defun image-add (to from val)
  (do-vectorized (i 0 (array-total-size to))
    (:unroll 2)
    (setf (f32-aref to i) (f32+ (f32-aref from i) val))))

(defparameter *HORZ* 800)
(defparameter *VERT* 800)

(defparameter *PERF-REPS* 1000)

(defun main ()
  (declare (type fixnum *HORZ* *VERT* *PERF-REPS*))  
  (let ((to   (make-array (* *HORZ* *VERT*) :element-type 'f32))
        (from (make-array (* *HORZ* *VERT*) :element-type 'f32)))
    (time (dotimes (_ *PERF-REPS*)
            (image-add to from 42.0)))))

(save-lisp-and-die "image-add" :executable t :toplevel #'main)
```

EDITED: On my i7-7700HQ CPU I get:

```
$ gcc -O3 image-add.c ./tictoc/build/libtictoc.a
$ ./a.out 
Elapsed time 0.124956 seconds.

$ gcc -O3 -march=native -mavx2 image-add.c ./tictoc/build/libtictoc.a
$ ./a.out
Elapsed time 0.116989 seconds.

$ ./image-add 
Evaluation took:
  0.072 seconds of real time
  0.070440 seconds of total run time (0.070236 user, 0.000204 system)
  97.22% CPU
  199,079,678 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

Comment: Though this is quite an old post but I thought you @Red.Cabin might still be interested.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `:lparallel` suggestion by @coredump, I was able to get consistent runs of 0.125 seconds, distinctly faster than gcc -O3's 0.175.  The various techniques suggested in comments of compiling the file and inlining the `image-add` function did not produce appreciable speedup. Here is the fastest code so far.

```
(load "~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")
(ql:quickload :lparallel)

(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))

(defparameter HORZ 800)
(defparameter VERT 800)

(defparameter PERF-REPS 1000)

(setf lparallel:*kernel* (lparallel:make-kernel 4))

(defun test ()
  (declare (type fixnum HORZ VERT PERF-REPS))
  (let ((to (make-array (* HORZ VERT) :element-type 'single-float))
        (fm (make-array (* HORZ VERT) :element-type 'single-float)))
    (time (dotimes (_ PERF-REPS)
            (lparallel:pmap-into to (lambda (x) (+ x 42f0)) fm)))))

(test)
```

EDIT: I will note that this isn't exactly fair: I added explicit parallelism to the Lisp code but not to the C code. However, it's notable how easy this was to do with Lisp. Because the chief advantage of Lisp over C in this scenario is code brevity and the relative ease of adding features like parallelism, the trade-off is in the right direction (of illustrating Lisp's relative flexibility).  I suspect that parallel C code (if and when I can get around to implementing it) will be faster again than the Lisp code.

Comment: In this case, there is no an advantage of Lisp over C at all, you're ignoring the fact you're using lparallel, which is a library and not a part of Common Lisp.  In C, you have many libraries that also portably ease parallel code.  What you should be after is in informing the Lisp compiler the best you can (assuming you already have the best algorithm, such as iterating columns inside rows) e.g. type declarations, low safety and high speed declarations.  Even so, you'll have a very hard time trying to make Lisp faster than C, because usually you can get it to be, at most, just as fast.